# POST boolean with javascript when change toggle checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, flask

Need to submit every change in toggle with POST. I'm use flask. And in templates want to change boolean status of table in database. Script work fine when i check to displaying on current template boolean status, but when i try to submit it can't work.
Template:

```
<form id="is_active" name="is_active" action="{{ url_for('activate_post', post_id=post.id) }}" method="POST">
<input id="toggleEvent" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Enabled" data-off="Disabled" data-offstyle="danger" data-onstyle="outline-success">
                </form>
<script type='text/javascript'>

  $("#toggleEvent").change(function() {
      if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
      $(this).val('true');
      }
      else {
      $(this).val('false');
      }
    $('toggleEvent').submit();
  });

</script>
```

Comment: possibly `$('#toggleEvent').parentNode.submit();` or similar ~ it is the `form` that takes the `submit` method

Answer (score 0):

You are not submitting the form
Replace this

```js
$('toggleEvent').submit();
```

with the following

```js
$('#is_active').submit();
```

I hope this works

Comment: any errors in the console? what is the action url there?

Comment: can't see errors. action url based on jinja and send to framework routing page( it's flask)

Comment: ok, check network tab and see whether the url is being called

Comment: use different value for name attribue and try